# Costura.Fody Embedded Library Namespaces Not Found

Tags: fody, fody-costura

I'm using Costura.Fody to embed a bunch of references in my project into a sort of master-library to remove the need to reference every single library in my API. Costura.Fody output shows that the other parts of my library are being embedded, but when I reference the DLL the embedded namespaces aren't being shown, so dependent projects won't build.

Opening the DLL in a text editor shows that the embedded namespaces *are* in the DLL but can't be detected in Visual Studio...

I'm using the default Costura.Fody weavers setup. Any advice? Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how Costura works. Costura embeds the other libraries into your main one, which means they're hidden if you only reference the main library.

To achieve the effect you want you're better off using a tool like ILMerge.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I'll take a look at ILMerge.